# Only print specific amount of Counter items, with decent formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

Trying to print out the top N most frequent used words in a text file. So far, I have the file system and the counter and everything working, just cant figure out how to print the certain amount I want in a pretty way. Here is my code.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def wordcount(user):
"""
Docstring for word count.
"""
file=input("Enter full file name w/ extension: ")
num=int(input("Enter how many words you want displayed: "))

with open(file) as f:
  text = f.read()

words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)

cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words]

word_counts = Counter(cap_words)


char, n = word_counts.most_common(num)[0]
print ("WORD: %s \nOCCURENCE: %d " % (char, n) + '\n')
```

Basically, I just want to go and make a loop of some sort that will print out the following...

For instance num=3

So it will print out the 3 most frequent used words, and their count.
WORD: Blah Occurrence: 3
Word: bloo Occurrence: 2
Word: blee Occurrence: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the most common elements and use a loop.

```
common = word_counts.most_common(num)[0]
for i in range(3):
    print("WORD: %s \nOCCURENCE: %d \n" % (common[i][0], common[i][1]))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just couldn't figure out the system in my head for some reason. Works perfectly now.

Comment: If someone could explain the downvote, would love to improve this answer (although I'm not sure how - it already solved the OP's issue).

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but since this answer is valid - I am balancing it with my vote ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would iterate "most common" as follows:

```
most_common = word_counts.most_common(num)  # removed the [0] since we're not looking only at the first item!    
for item in most_common:
        print("WORD: {} OCCURENCE: {}".format(item[0], item[1]))
```

Two comments:
1. Use `format()` to format strings instead of `%` - you'll thank me later for this advice!
2. This way you'll be able to iterate *any* number of "top N" results without hardcoding "3" into your code.